# Remove <a href > from generated url in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a user input where i need to check if the user enters a keyword. (e.g. git 123)
If i the keyword is detected i create a link pointing to git issue 123. The link replaces the Keyword in the user input with the issue name as a link.

I use `$finishedUrL = "<a href =".$url." title =".$text.">".$text."</a>";` to create the url.

Then i save the whole thing to a myslq database.

My problem is the edit function. It gets the input from the Database and just shows the whole   `<a href>` thing from above.
Is there a way to just show the link, issue name or the original user input in the edit field without reworking the edit function to replace it with some pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text in the database has the keyword replaced with the HTML-link and you didn't store the original text, you would have to "undo"/reverse that replacement in some way or another to get the original text back.

I don't feel like this is a clean solution however. I suggest that you store the original text in the database, show that when editing, and do a replacement of the keyword with the HTML-link on the fly when you want the text that is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I thought on that as well. But i need the link on multiple locations and for that it is quite convinient to have the link in the db. While i have only the edit field where the <a href  really matters. So i am thinking just undoing it for the edit is less work. Than doing the link replacement on multiple positions.

Comment: Well if you sure that's easier then that's the way to go :) However you could also store the original and have a PHP function do the replacement after querying the database, or - if by multiple places you mean that multiple backend applications access the database - you could even move that to a SQL stored procedure so that you really have the functionality in a common place. Or you could store both the original text and the text with the HTML-links in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use strip_tags function to remove any HTML tags which only keeps the value in the tag.

```
<?php
$userInput = 123;
$finishedUrl = '<a href="http://example.com" title="Example">' . $userInput .'</a>';

$originalUserInput= strip_tags($finishedUrL);
```

Although, I strongly suggest just to save plain user input in datbase and display on anchor tag where ever required.